# SelectionChanged Event handler for ComboBox continuously going off even without a change

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

In C# WPF, I am trying to handle the SelectionChanged event for a bunch of ComboBoxes. I have narrowed down the issue to a single line of code that Id rather not get rid of but might have to. Here is my code simplified to contain only what is necessary:

XAML

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectViewList}" SelectedIndex="{Binding ObjectViewListIndex}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
             <GridViewColumn Header="Object Type" Width="80">
                 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ObjTypeComboBox}" SelectedItem="{Binding ObjType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="Element_Changed"/>
                     </DataTemplate>
                 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The issue seems to be coming from the line `ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ObjTypeComboBox}"` Which I am using to be able to bind the ComboBox ItemsSource to a list (ObjTypeComboBox) that I have in my ViewModel because the ItemsSource Binding done above in the ListView takes away my ability to use regular binding to ViewModel properties and methods from within the ListView. The alternative would be having each column in my list contain its own ObjTypeComboBox list and I would have to keep a bunch of instances and update them all. Maybe there is a different way to be able to bind to my ObjTypeComboBox that doesn't trigger the SelectionChanged event, I'm not even sure why it just infinitely triggers the event maybe someone can explain it to me.

**Edit:**
I ended up "fixing" it with these lines of code:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ExampleCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Instead of handling the event in my code behind I use behaviors to be able to call a ICommand in my ViewModel (which is what Id rather anyways because before I was calling ViewModel method in code behind). But I still would like to know why this works because before it was constantly triggering SelectionChanged but now that I handle it differently it doesn't???

Comment: Maybe set `Mode=OneTime` to the binding? Assuming the `ObjTypeComboBox` list doesn't change....

Comment: @lidqy The issue is even if that does work I need it to be able to change